# Pauli matrices in curved space-time

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spinors

I am studying the chapter on spin-1/2 particles in Kerr geometry from "The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes" by S. Chandrasekhar. I have trouble in understanding how he arrives at the generalized Pauli matrices in (67):

$$\sigma^i_{AB'}=\begin{matrix} l^i & m^i \\ \bar{m}^i & n^i \end{matrix},$$

where $A$,$B'$ are spinor indices and ($l^i$,$n^i$,$m^i$,$\bar{m}_i$) constitute a null basis.

This is what I understood:

1. Null vectors in Minkowski space can be visualised as Riemann spheres. This allows us to obtain a mapping between null vectors and complex numbers as:

   $$\xi^A\bar{\xi^{A'}} \leftrightarrow l^{\mu}$$

   (Side question: As far as I understood, this is just a stereographic projection. And hence the mapping between null vectors and complex numbers should be one-one. But if $l^\mu$ is determined by $\xi^A$, it could also be determined by $\xi^Ae^{i\phi}$, and hence the mapping is not one-one. And this leads to the flag representation of spinors. Where am I going wrong?)
2. Motivated by the above mapping, we define a mapping between arbitrary vectors and rank 2 spinors as:

   $$X^{AB'} \leftrightarrow k^{\mu}$$

   From the structure of the stereographic projection, we conclude that the Van der Waerden  symbols $\sigma^i_{AB'}$ are the familiar Pauli matrices.
3. So far we were in Minkowski space (or the local tetrad frame). Now we wish to carry the $\sigma^i_{AB'}$ to the global space-time. And that somehow leads to the generalised Pauli matrix (67).

Am I thinking in the right direction? It would be great if you specifically build upon Chandrasekhar's text. Particularly, I am confused about the difference between the symbols  $\sigma^i_{AB'}$ and $\sigma^{(a)}_{AB'}$. Since the entire formalism of spinors seems to be built upon Minkowski space (local or global), what is the meaning of this distinction?

(Another side question regarding spinor indices: When raising and lowering spinor indices, Chandrasekhar contracts the second and first index of the levi-civita symbol respectively. But Srednicki says that the second index has to be contracted in each case. I don't get what decides which index is to be contracted.)

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am tired of getting confused about this stuff.